# Timer not starting in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, timer, refresh

net program that uses excel as a datasource. I then fill a datagridview with this datasource and make changes to the dataset via the datagridview. I'm trying to find a way to refresh this dataset via a button that will update the values after a change. My only problem is that I'm trying to set up a timer in my refresh method but it never initializes/starts. I can't figure out why, from what I've found online the way to start a timer in vb.net is to set the timer variable to enabled = true. I've stepped into my debugger and found that the timer never starts. Here is my code below, if there is anyone who can figure out why this timer isn't starting I would greatly appreciate your help!

```
Dim mytimer As New System.Timers.Timer
Sub refresh()

   write2Size()



   mytimer.timer = New System.Timers.Timer(20000)
  'Starting Timer
   mytimer.Enabled = True
   Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor



   AddHandler mytimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent



   objworkbook.Save()
   objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save()

   myDS.Clear()
   retrieveUpdate()

  'Setting the cursor back to normal here
       Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
   End Sub

   Private Shared Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)

   Console.WriteLine(&quot;The Elapsed event was raised at {0}, e.SignalTime)
   End Sub
```

Comment: Is there omitted code between the where you enable the timer and where you disable the timer? If there is omitted code, indicate with a comment where it is, and generally what it does. Also, it will be 20 seconds before the Timer fires the first time. Did you wait that long?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a timer here
Dim mytimer As New System.Timers.Timer
but you only assign a handler to the one you create inside the Refresh routine.

Would have expected

```
Dim mytimer As New System.Timers.Timer(20000)
AddHandler mytimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
```

then

```
Private Shared Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)

   Console.WriteLine(&quot;The Elapsed event was raised at {0}, e.SignalTime)
   Refresh()
End Sub
```

and something like

```
Sub refresh()

   myTimer.Enabled = False
   // refresh the doings
   myTimer.Enabled = True
End sub
```

Excuse the lack of VBness, I'm a C# boy.

Comment: There is a syntax error with the AddHandler if you take it out of the method

Comment: Put inside some other method then, formcreate or show or whatever then. Point is you need some piece of code that will set up the timer's OnTimedEvent handler for the first time.